# ThreeJS FBXLoader import via cdn not working

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, cdn, es6-modules

im trying to import ThreeJS and the ThreeJS FBXLoader example via cdn. For this purpose I have created the following imports.

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three';
import * as FBXLoader from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader';
</script>
```

The import of ThreeJS is successful because I can access `THREE` afterwards to render a scene without any problems. However, the FBXLoader import fails with the following error message.

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #canvas {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    </style>
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three';
    //ThreeJS working fine when commenting out this import
    import * as FBXLoader from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee);
    const parent = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, parent.offsetWidth / parent.offsetHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    //const loader = new FBXLoader(manager);

    renderer.setSize(parent.offsetWidth, parent.offsetHeight);
    parent.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    });

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Why can't the FBXLoader access the previously imported THREE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to import from 'jsm' subpath to ensure compatibility between three.js es6 module and the es6 plugin module (in your case FBXLoader).

For me adding a version after 'three' in the import path fixed the problem.

```
import { FBXLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader';
```

I don't know why though.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That solved it for me. Can someone explain why this (or the version) works?